# Can't omit default params when call Kotlin's function from Java in Android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to write function (createSend) that has 3 params.
But only last (`callback`) must be required. So to do this I use default (`null`) value of optional params.

```
fun createSend(
        amount: Double? = null, currency: String? = null, callback: Callback<Send>
    ) {
}
```

and here client call (java code in Android project):

```
TransportService.INSTANCE.createSend(12.1, "USD", new DefaultRestClientCallback<Send>() {
...}
```

Nice it's work fine.

But now I want to omit first param (`amount`). 
I try this:

```
TransportService.INSTANCE.createSend( "USD", new DefaultRestClientCallback<Send>() {
...
}
```

and now I get compile error:

```
                TransportService.INSTANCE.createSend( "USD", new DefaultRestClientCallback<Send>() {
                                         ^
  required: Double,String,Callback<Send>
  found: String,<anonymous DefaultRestClientCallback<Send>>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: You should add more information if you use multiple languages. If it wasn't for the `new` keyword, I wouldn't have noticed that you are calling the function from Java instead of Kotlin.

Comment: I call Kotlin's code from java

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling the function from Java code, you need to annotate the function in Kotlin with `@JVMOverlads` to generate the Java overloads.

```
@JVMOverloads
fun createSend(
    amount: Double? = null, currency: String? = null, callback: Callback<Send>
) {
}
```

**However this will not work if you still have parameters after the one you leave out.** This is common with normal overloads in java as well. Because its not clear which ones you leave out.

*Note: Should you try to call the function from Kotlin like this, you can used named parameters to leave out a parameter that is not the last. But java doesn't have that.*

Comment: "TransportService.INSTANCE.createSend("USD", new DefaultRestClientCallback<Send>() { " -> Now I get error: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'java.lang.Double'

Comment: I see, so you have the same problem as you would have in Kotlin, because there are still parameters after the one you leave out. And Java doesn't have named parameters to solve that. Then I'm afraid you will need to either reorder the parameters or explicitly make another function that doesn't require the first parameter.

Comment: It is `@JvmOverloads` for me (Jvm instead of JVM)